# Useful node.js middlewares

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

What is a node.js middleware / framework you personally found interesting / useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Connect from Sencha Labs as middleware. http://github.com/senchalabs/connect

Answer (score 2):

Based on the few frameworks I've played around with so far, [Express](http://expressjs.com/) seems to me like one of the top candidates, if you're looking for a web framework.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules) list of modules for node.js. Express seems to be the most mature, but of course it depends on what you are looking for.